# Ubuntu 10.04 unstable, System menu incomplete after failed upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-10.04, upgrade

I hadn't used my Ubuntu 10.04 laptop for a week or so, and when I came back to it, it had a message from the Update Manager asking to update 800+ files.  So I said OK.  It downloaded the packages and started the update.

Since this was taking quite a while, I went to work on my desktop, and occasionally peeked over at the laptop to see how it was doing.  After awhile, the Update Manager dialog box said something about "Recovering from package failure".  I clicked on the Details icon.  It was processing a bunch of files, and then it just stopped.  After five minutes, I gave up and restarted the system.  I noticed that now there was a new version of Grub (1.98+20100804-4), and also a new kernel (2.6.32-24).   But when I selected the new kernel, it said "Gave up waiting for root device" and the system immediately dropped into a command shell for initramfs.

If I select the previous kernel (2.6.32-23) in Grub, right after the Ubuntu logo comes up I get a message "There was a problem with the configuration server.  /usr/lib/libcong2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256".

After logging in, my desktop the System Menu doesn't appear to be complete.  It is missing Preferences and Adminsitration.  All there is are entries for Help and Support, About GNOME, About Ubunutu,Lock Screen, Log Out..., and Shut Down...

Any ideas on how I can recover from this mess and get back a stable system?  I am an experienced programmer but still somewhat of a Ubuntu newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-running the upgrade

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get-upgrade`

---

Try removing the package completely

`sudo apt-get remove gnome-accessibility-themes_2.30.2-1_all && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Follow it up clearing out the apt-cache and reinstalling it

`sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get install gnome-accessibility-themes_2.30.2-1_all`

Comment: I did the apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade in the terminal window.  After reading the packages, apt-get update said:  W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org sid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B.
I went ahead and ran apt-get update, and it said (continued in next comment):

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/desktopcouch_0.6.6-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-accessibility-themes_2.30.2-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Ran it again and got the same thing.  When I rebooted, my System menu was restored (thank you); however I still get the message "There was a problem with the configuration server. /usr/lib/libcong2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256". when logging in.

Comment: @tcrosely Updated my answer, please check and report back.

Comment: It tried removing the packages manually as you suggested, and encountered another error, such that now when I try to run sudo apt-get anything it says E: dpkg was interrupted, and to run sudo dpkg --configure -a.  However when I do that, it runs a while then right after the line Setting up hal (0.5.14-3) it says Restarting dbus, then the entire desktop goes away.    At that point I have to restart the computer.  Rerunning dpkg --configure -a just repeats so I am in a loop.

Comment: Ok, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and follow it up by `sudo apt-get upgrade`. this *should* fix everything

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear in my last comment, when I type "sudo dpkg --configure -a", after the second line of output (Restarting dbus) the terminal exits, and the whole desktop disappears and I have to reboot.  When I get back to a new terminal, the same thing happens.  So I can't ever get to the point where I can enter the "sudo apt-get upgrade" command.

Comment: @tcrosley can you boot into recovery/failsafe mode( whichever it is called) and try just a `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: I still get the message E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem  which crashes my system as explained above

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --audit`. That should tell what's causing problems @trcos

Comment: Among other things, it said to run "sudo dpkg --configure hal" so I tried this because this is where it was resetting the system.  To get around the dbus problem I ran it in a virtual terminal.  The output said:
* Starting hardware abstraction layer
invoke-rc.d: initscript hal, action "start" failed
dpkg: error processing hal (--configure)
so I guess that is whre it is getting stuck.

Comment: Hmm can you remove and reinstall @tcros `sudo apt-get remove hal && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get install hal`

Comment: No, that's the catch-22 in all of this, I can't do any apt-gets because every time I just get the message "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'"

Comment: Dang. I'm not sure how to proceed @tcrosley. I'd suggest you do a clean reinstall. Else maybe a post at Ubuntu Forums -> http://ubuntuforums.org  Perhaps the folks there can give you a better solution.

Comment: @Sathya, thanks for all your help.  I've backed up my /home directory and /etc directories on a USB HD formatted with ext4 and and am going to do a reinstall of 10.04 tonight.

Comment: I did a clean install of 10.04.1 which got me a working version of the latest kernel.

Comment: Good to know it's working fine now @tcrosley !